# mongodb replica sets on two physical machines

Tags: mongodb

The two options I can think of for replica sets on two boxes would be as follows:

1. 2 VMs on each machine.
2. 2 mongod instances on each machine.

Is either of these better than the other or totally imbecile in comparison to the real solution?

This is part of my research for a litte side project: http://bearassbear.blogspot.com/2010/10/idea.html

Any help/advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the article you're looking for is this one:

[I have four servers and I want two shard](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/08/30/return-of-the-mongo-mailbag/).

This should get you started on a sharded replica set configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I actually read some posts of hers on replica sets already. My data won't be big enough for sharding to be important, but that was still a good read. The first half of the article will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of a research I dont see why it would hurt. If you were to do this in a production environment, I would definitely look into having separate servers for redundancies reason. What if the host machine holding the 2 VMs crash? So much for high availability.

Comment: my coworkers have been setting up some ec2 instances with AWS and I'd really like to get on that bandwagon. I think the 4 virtual servers would help me on my way to that goal. I'm trying to get tips/resources/tricks for setting this up, so that as I learn, I learn the right way.

Comment: Understood, I've never used ec2 but that's a great way to learn and get a feel for it. I signed up with vps.net and I'm hoping to deploy a sharded an environment once my app goes live.